# <activity> does not have valid android:name

Tags: java, android

I have trouble with the INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED error where I looked into logcat where the following was my error:

*W/PackageParser: /data/app/vmdl-1226238136.tmp (at Binary XML file line #27):  does not have valid android:name*

I looked into my manifest code and after searching through a lot of forums (adding . before my activity name, adding big letters and etcetera) it does not work.

What is wrong with my activity name?

Down below is my manifest code;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="R.ekryt">

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
  </application>

 </manifest>
```

Comment: Which line is `at Binary XML file line #27` <---this

Comment: it's the very end of the manifest file, </manifest> is at line #26

Comment: please check your all layout files properly,there maybe possibility of issue

Comment: and what exactly am I looking for there? :)

Comment: check package name, maybe you changed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> package="R.ekryt"
> ```

Android app packages need to be all lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

replace this activity android:name=".MainActivity"
 with

activity android:name="your_package_name.MainActivity"

and also check your package, package name doesnt contain Capital letters but your package name seems to be have Capital letter R